# How to slience the device (either ios or android) completely in certain time of the day with React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to build an app that mute the device in certain time of the day with React Native, that says, it should start running in the background once the phone is started. Is that possible? Or its something had to be done in the actual native code? I did research online but can't find a solution at all.

Comment: In Objective-C (iOS) Language, there is an option to perform an operation using `NSTimer`. Which is a help to call a method after a certain time. Try with this keyword for React Native.